# Using a dynamic parameter in the SELECT clause

Tags: sql, filemaker

I'm attempting to use a dynamic parameter in the `SELECT` clause with this code:

```
ExecuteSQL (
       "
       SELECT ? 
       FROM \"KPI\"
       WHERE \"Year\" IN (2016)
       "
       ;
       ""; "" ; "MarketingActivities"
)
```

It returns this **unexpected result**, which interprets the string literally rather than as a field name.

```
MarketingActivities
MarketingActivities
MarketingActivities
...
```

This code **does give the intended result but is not dynamic**:

```
ExecuteSQL (
       "
       SELECT \"MarketingActivities\" 
       FROM \"KPI\"
       WHERE \"Year\" IN (2016)
       "
       ;
       ""; "" 
)
```

Result:

```
318
75
235
...
```

This is with FileMaker 15. The parameter is stored in a field as a global variable, but here I wrote it out explicitly. I've also tried variations of the dynamic parameter:

```
\"Marketing Activities\"
'Marketing Activities'
```

I haven't had similar problems when using dynamic parameters in the `WHERE` clause. **Is there a way to resolve this problem and also allow the `SELECT` clause to be dynamic?**

Answer (score 1):

You can not specify a column using a parameter. It is much easier to achieve by using modified calculation:

```
 ExecuteSQL ("
       SELECT " & "MarketingActivities" & " 
       FROM \"KPI\"
       WHERE \"Year\" IN (2016)
       ";""; "" )
```

Instead of the string you can use a variable or a value from a field, making the column selection dynamic

Comment: Just realised, the last line of SQL statement should be WHERE Year = 2016

Answer (score 0):

I used this [link](http://www.filemaker.com/help/12/fmp/html/func_ref3.33.6.html):

Example:

```
ExecuteSQL("select sum(S.salary) from Employees E join Salary S on E.EmpID = S.EmpID where E.Department = ?"; ""; ""; Department)
```

So for you this should be the following:

```
ExecuteSQL (
   "
   SELECT ? 
   FROM \"KPI\"
   WHERE \"Year\" IN (2016)
   "
   ;
   ""; "" ; MarketingActivities)
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but the example you've shown involves a parameter in the `WHERE` clause. And when executing the code, I get this error: "The specified table cannot be found". It highlights the word "MarketingActivities".

Comment: This is because it is passes the value of MarketingActivities column of the current record as a parameter, not the reference to the column itself

Comment: Try adding the scheme name to the table name: schemename.MarketingActivities.